# Recreate .dbj file from information found in .bst file

Tags: bibtex, custom-bib

I have a `.bst` file of unknown origin that contains the following information:

```
%% This is file `iatbr.bst',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% merlin.mbs  (with options: `,ay,nat,nm-rev1,keyxyr,dt-beg,yr-par,yrp-x,note-yr,thtit-a,trnum-it,vol-bf,vnum-sp,volp-blk,bkpg-x,isbn,issn,url,url-blk,edpar,bkedcap,blk-com,blknt,ppx,ed,abr,xedn,and-xcom,etal-it,em-it,nfss')

%%% combined with
%% merlin.mbs  (with options: `,ay,nat,nm-rev1,keyxyr,yr-par,aymth,yrp-x,note-yr,thtit-a,trnum-it,vol-bf,vnum-sp,volp-blk,bkpg-x,isbn,issn,url,url-blk,edpar,bkedcap,blk-com,blknt,ppx,ed,abr,xedn,and-xcom,etal-it,em-it,nfss')
```

How does this translate to input for the `makebst` program? Is there a way to use the string of options directly? Is the "combined with" part something that `makebst` would generate, or is this a hint that the results of two `makebst` runs were combined manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found in Section 2.1 of the [`makebst` documentation](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/bibref/makebst.pdf). In this case, the file `iatbr.dbj` with the first set of options could look like this:

```
\input docstrip
\preamble
This is for ...
\endpreamble
\postamble
End of ...
\endpostamble
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\generate{\file{iatbr.bst}{\from{merlin.mbs}{,ay,nat,nm-rev1,keyxyr,dt-beg,yr-par,yrp-x,note-yr,thtit-a,trnum-it,vol-bf,vnum-sp,volp-blk,bkpg-x,isbn,issn,url,url-blk,edpar,bkedcap,blk-com,blknt,ppx,ed,abr,xedn,and-xcom,etal-it,em-it,nfss}}}
\endbatchfile
```

Running this file via `tex iatbr.dbj` creates the file `iatbr.bst`.

The "combined with" part probably means that the output of two `docstrip` runs was merged manually.

The question carries a misconception: `makebst` is a program that would *create* a `.dbj` file that contains a list of options. If the options are already given, they can only be fed into a manually crafted `.dbj` file (as above). The options are documented in Section 9 of the [`merlin.mbs` documentation](http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/merlin.pdf).